# Cannot create uri from simple jade form

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a simple jade form with 2 fields and I want to get the input from these fields and generate a URI that conforms with my API.

My jade form is this:

```
doctype html
html
  include head
  body
    form(method='GET', action='/' + firstName + '/' + lastName)
      | firstName:
      br
      input(type='text', name='firstName', value = firstName)
      br
      | lastName:
      br
      input(type='text', name='lastName', value = lastName)
      br
      br
      input(type='submit', value='Submit')
```

I would expect then to get something like `/John/Doe` which I can handle with my API.

Instead I get `undefined/undefined?firstName=John&lastName=Doe`

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with maze-le, you can't do that with Jade. Jade has server-side template javascript, but what you need is client-side javascript. With jQuery it might look like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('form input[type=submit]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    firstName = $('form input[name=firstName]').val();
    lastName = $('form input[name=lastName]').val();
    window.location.href = '/' + firstName + '/' + lastName;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so this should work if I just create a small javascript file with the above code and add it in Jade?

Comment: Yes, it should. But you need to add jQuery lib: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, even though the logic seems right. When I fill the forms and press submit nothing happens. I also tried with `window.location.replace` and `window.location.assign` and that didn't solve it. I guess I will have to brush up my jquery a bit.

Comment: Here is a full html/js file that works on my system https://gist.github.com/asinyagin/d27e82b537eea57f507e

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, turns out that the problem was Firefox (and IE for that matter). Testing with Chrome works. I still have trouble with my cloud environment and jade but it shouldn't be too hard to resolve. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to accomplish with jade / html only, at least not with the GET-path, that you want. `firstName` and `lastName` are beeing interpreted, when the jade-interpreter hits the line:

```
form(method='GET', action='/' + firstName + '/' + lastName)
```

At this time, both variables are undefined. As with most template-languages jade is lexically scoped, that means in your case: These variables havent been seen or defined before, therefore they are undefined.

Some suggestions for possible solutions:

1. On the Server-Side: Treat firstName and lastName as paramters, not parts of a specific uri-path. Your server then should evaluate the param-string: `firstName=John&lastName=Doe`. That works with jade/html-only. But you have to define a specific path for your action.
2. Use javascript to do the client-server communication. This way, you can manipulate every aspect of your server-calls.